# Check if download / upload in progress

Tags: linux, windows, download, cmd, terminal

Is there any way to check if there's any active download / upload (file transfer) using a command in command prompt ? I would also be interested if there's anyway to check the same thing under linux os?

Comment: What kind of download?

Comment: well, about any kind.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "download" is a very soft term. But on linux

```
lsof -i
```

might come close to what you want. "...this option selects the listing of all Internet and x.25 (HP-UX) network files."

Answer (score 0):

You could check the packet status of socket on which the data transfer is being handled. But I don't think that this will give you specific information on whether the "download" is activem, because there are many ways of handling "download/upload".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tcpdump](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_tcpdump.htm) and check the headers to find out about upload download.